# Cannot convert a symbolic Tensor (dense_2_target_2:0) to a numpy array

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, svm

I'm trying to implement SVM as the last layer of a CNN for classification, I'm trying to implement this code:

```
def custom_loss_value(y_true, y_pred):
  print(y_true)
  print(y_pred)
  X = y_pred
  print(X)
  Y = y_true
  Predict = []
  Prob = []
  scaler = StandardScaler()
  # X = scaler.fit_transform(X)
  param_grid = {'C': [0.1, 1, 8, 10], 'gamma': [0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1]}
  SVM = GridSearchCV(SVC(kernel='rbf',probability=True), cv=3, param_grid=param_grid, scoring='auc', verbose=1)
  SVM.fit(X, Y)
  Final_Model = SVM.best_estimator_
  Predict = Final_Model.predict(X)
  Prob = Final_Model.predict_proba(X)
  return categorical_hinge(tf.convert_to_tensor(Y, dtype=tf.float32), tf.convert_to_tensor(Predict, dtype=tf.float32))
    

sgd = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(lr=0.001, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
model.compile(loss=custom_loss_value, optimizer=sgd, metrics=['accuracy'])
```

I'm getting the error: **Cannot convert a symbolic Tensor (dense_2_target_2:0) to a numpy array**
on the line **SVM.fit(X,Y)**
I also tried converting the y_true and y_pred to np array but was getting error then also

Comment: You cannot use non-tensorflow functions in a loss, you would have to implement an SVM using tensorflow inside the loss, not using scikit-learn functions.

Comment: And what libraries I can use or any other way to solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

To train a neural network with gradient descent, you need a model to be differentiable. So, you need to be able to take a gradient w.r.t. every trainable parameter.

Some problems arise in your code:

1. You can't directly train an SVM inside a Keras loss function. It
   takes a TensorFlow tensor and uses TF ops. The output is also a
   Tensorflow tensor. sklearn can work with NumPy arrays or lists but
   not tensors.
2. It is very hard and practically not useful to train SVM through backpropagation. [Something about it can be read here.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/158712/how-to-train-an-svm-via-backpropagation)

You can train SVM on top of pretrained model instead of fully-connected layer.